# Isend/Irecv doesn`t work but Send/Recv does

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90

When I use Send/Recv my code works but when I replace Send/Recv with Isend/Irecv it yields segmentation fault. But before going anywhere else I wanted to verify whether the following snippet seems alrite or not.

The rest of the code should be fine as Send/Recv works; but I haven`t pasted here as its a long code.

```
    INTEGER :: IERR,TASKID,NUMTASKS,SPANX,SPANY,SPANZ,PROCSX,PROCSY,PROCSZ,STAT,STATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),ISTAT(MPI_STATUS_SIZE,52)
    INTEGER,DIMENSION(1:52) :: REQ

 ALLOCATE(RCC(IIST:IIEND,JJST:JJEND,KKST:KKEND),STAT=IERR)  
 IF (IERR /=0) PRINT*,'ERROR IN RCC BY',TASKID

 DO I=1,52
 REQ(I)=MPI_REQUEST_NULL  
 ENDDO

 IF (TASKID.NE.0) THEN   
 NT=TASKID
 CALL MPI_ISEND(RCC(IIST:IIEND,JJST:JJEND,KKST:KKEND),SIZE(RCC),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,8,MPI_COMM_WORLD,REQ(NT),IERR)
 ENDIF

 IF (TASKID.EQ.0) THEN     
 DO NT = 1,26
 CALL MPI_IRECV(CC(RSPANX(NT):RSPANXE(NT),RSPANY(NT):RSPANYE(NT),RSPANZ(NT):RSPANZE(NT)),SIZECC(NT),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,NT,8,MPI_COMM_WORLD,REQ(NT+26),IERR)   
 ENDDO       
 ENDIF  

 CALL MPI_WAITALL(52,REQ,ISTAT,IERR)

  DEALLOCATE(RCC,STAT=IERR) 
  IF (IERR /=0) PRINT*,'ERROR IN DEALLOCATE RCC BY',TASKID 

  CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)
  RETURN
  END
```

However, when I use Isend/Irecv the following line doesn`t give Segmentation fault.

```
  CALL MPI_IRECV(CC(RSPANX(NT),RSPANY(NT),RSPANZ(NT)),SIZECC(NT),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,NT,8,MPI_COMM_WORLD,REQ(NT+26),IERR)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I would suggest using a debugger to find the source of the segmentation fault here.

Answer (score 8):

Calling asynchronous communication routines like `MPI_ISEND` and `MPI_IRECV` with array sections, e.g. `RCC(IIST:IIEND,JJST:JJEND,KKST:KKEND)`, is very dangerous. The reason is that due to limitations in the older Fortran standards most MPI implementations do not provide proper interfaces for those routines and the compiler copies the data from the array section into a temporary contiguous storage, which then gets passed to the subroutine. The segmentation fault probably occurs due to this temporary storage being freed on return from `MPI_ISEND`/`MPI_IRECV` before the actual data transfer takes place. You can prevent this from happening by manually allocating the contiguous array and copying the data there.

On the other side, `CC(RSPANX(NT),RSPANY(NT),RSPANZ(NT))` does not refer to a section of the array but rather to the location of a single element. No temporary copy of the data is created in this case.

MPI-3.0 provides an improved set of Fortran bindings `mpi_f08`, which uses modern features in Fortran 2008 and TS 29113 to mark such arguments with the `ASYNCHRONOUS` attribute and to enable safe passing of arrays with different dimensions (`TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..)`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try what you have suggested.