# Non-blocking MPI calls in Fortran, safe or not?

Tags: fortran, mpi, nonblocking

In *Using MPI*, Gropp *et al.* give a fairly detailed discussion of using non-blocking MPI sends and receives, and illustrate them with Fortran code.  However, in *Using Advanced MPI*, chapter 11, "Working with Modern Fortran", the same (pretty much) authors warn that Fortran compilers don't really understand non-blocking subroutines and aggressively optimize and so they might optimize code in a way that is erroneous.  They then illustrate a semi-portable way of protecting against this.

So I am confused.  I have seen a ton of non-blocking MPI operations in Fortran, and have written more than a few myself.  And there doesn't seem to be any problem with it.  So what is the truth?  It's unsafe but many people have just been getting lucky over the years?

UPDATE: In case anyone is interested, I figure "fair usage" allows me to copy the authors' example here:

```
    Use mpi_f08
    INTEGER :: rbuf(1000000), rval
    TYPE(MPI_Request) :: req
    call MPI_IRECV(rbuf, 1000000, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req)
    call MPI_WAIT(req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE)
    rval = rbuf(1)
```

The authors point out the a particularly aggressive Fortran compiler could, following its own rules, rearrange the last couple of lines to

```
rval = rbuf(1)
call MPI_WAIT(req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE)
```

which could result in a total mess.

Comment: There _can_ be problems, but to limit elaboration, are you interested in Fortran 2008 bindings or explicitly "old" ones?

Comment: @francescalus   Well, the "old" ones for the moment, because of the code base I work with.  But I'm sure I'll have to move to 2008 eventually.

Comment: One case with MPI implementations which do not support asynchronous communication is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18303064/3157076). Is that the kind of example the authors had in mind?

Comment: @francescalus  No, array sections aren't the issue they were discussing at that point.  If you're interested, I went ahead and put their code snippet into the question.

Comment: That `mpi_irecv` call has only 7 arguments and `type(mpi_request)`, so must be a Fortran 2008 binding. A more complete example may help. (Also `rbif` should be `rbuf`?)

Comment: That's why `rval` should really be `asynchronous`. Do they not mention it?

Comment: Possibly important: In the above code snippet have do they have `Use mpi_f08`. But in practice don't worry. I've used async comms for years and array sections excluded you won't run into this problem.

Comment: @VladimirF  Yes, they mention it.  I'm just really confused because 1) they don't mention it in their first book, where they discuss non-blocking calls in Fortran at length and 2) I have edited/run many Fortran codes with non-blocking calls, and no one ever worries about `asynchronous`.  Have my dozens of users just been getting lucky all this time?

Comment: @francescalus   Yes Fortran 2008, and yes `rbif` is `rbuf`.  Made the correction, thanks.  I don't really have a more complete example.  I'm just going on what they said.

Comment: @IanBush   Yes, this is `mpi_f08`.  And glad to hear your experience.  Consistent with mine.  I was reading their text and thinking, "*Great!*  *Now* you tell me!"

Comment: The Fortran 2008 binding defines `TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..), ASYNCHRONOUS :: buf` for the first argument, so I guess the `ASYNCHRONOUS` attribute is in principle mandatory (?)

Comment: @tueda It's my understanding that an object can have the asynchronous attribute in some scoping units, but not others, so no it isn't mandatory. That's not to say it wouldn't be a good idea here, as might be Volatile, but I don't think it is required.

Comment: @IanBush: Yes, the F2018 standard contains an example where the asynchronous attribute is added to a variable inside a block scope (exactly in conjunction with non-blocking MPI usage).